SPL recency requirements after skill test
According to SFCL.160 SPL – Recency requirements an SPL holders shall exercise SPL privileges only if in the last 24 months before the planned flight they completed two training flights with an FI(S).

There is a specific exemption if the pilot has passed a proficiency check. My question is what happens if the pilot just passed the skill test for the for the purpose of issuing the licence? Does it mean your SPL does not yet meet the recency requirements until the pilot has performed the two training flights with a FI(S) after the skill test?

Typically a check flight trumps a review.  i.e. the "skill test" you mention would also count as a proficiency check and start the 24 month clock ticking.

@MichaelHall that's how I interpret it as well, but they only explicitly mention proficiency check they could have easily added an OR for the skill test. So it feels like this is explicitly omited.

You can do either point 1 OR point 2, meaning that if you do the "skill test" mentioned in point 2, you no longer need the 2 training flights with a FI(S) mentioned in point 1 (ii).
If you talk about the skill test after which you obtain the license (from student pilot to an actual pilot) - YES you have the privileges (you just passed a "skill test").
After the skill test, you have 24 months ahead with the SPL privileges!
They do mention the "or" just at the end of point 1 (ii) - or before point 2: "two training flights with an FI(S); or".
--- short explanation ---
This rule is for the case in which you take a longer break from flying (24 months at least). Because of that, you might get "out of hand" ("forgetting" how to fly) and not pilot as well as before, including some safety risks.
So you have to start flying again to "remember" or "train again" your skill. Meaning that you have to do 5h of flight + 15 lunches + 2 FI(S) flights (either with instructor or solo but under supervision) - after which you have the privileges back, and another 24 months start.
But in case you are confident that you can handle it - request a flight with a FE(S), which it is "based on the skill test for SPL", after which (if you pass) you have the privileges, without doing everything written in point 1.
In case you will not take a break - you will constantly add more and more hours to these 5 hours, more and more launches, so you will always have the requirements in the last 24 months, just remember to do the 2 flights with FI(S).

I hope this answer helped you, and if you have any questions, do not hesitate to ask!
Captain Pelican

Yes I am specifically referring to the scenario of passing a skill test after which you obtain the license (from student pilot to actual pilot). That's indeed how I see it as well, found it a bit strange they mention proficiency flight but not a skill test explicitly. Thanks for the confirmation though.

@max, But before you pass the skill test you are not yet an SPL holder, therefore you cannot exercise SPL privileges, therefore the entire section is not (yet) applicable.  Right?  In other words, "once you have passed the skill test the following recency requirements apply" is implied.

True there could be a confusion between proficiency flight and skill test, but tho.. they basically mean the same thing:) I'm glad my answered help:) And what @MichaelHall mentioned is very correct^^ you must pass the "first" skill test for the recency requirements rule to start
